# I am not able to understand the error in this Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to find the error in this. It gives the error that you have not created the function life_left or it is not able to find it.

How many times do you want them to fight ? 5

#### Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):    
>   File "main.py", line 42, in <module>    
>     start(7)    
>   File "main.py", line 39, in start    
>     arr[number].attack(guns[guns_number])    
>   File "main.py", line 19, in attack    
>     life_left(self.life)    
>  NameError: name 'life_left' is not defined
> ```

#### Code:

```
import random
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.life = 20

    def attack(self,gun):
        if (self.life <= 0):
            print("Dead")
        else:
            if gun is "AK47":
                self.life = self.life - 5
                life_left(self.life)
            elif gun is "Magnum":
                self.life = self.life - 4
                life_left(self.life)
            else:
                self.life = self.life - 1
                life_left(self.life)

    def life_left(life):
         print ("Life  :  " , str(life))


def start(players):
    a = 1
    arr = []
    while a <= players:
    arr.append("player" + str(a))
    arr[a-1] = Enemy()
    #print (arr[a-1])
    a += 1
    enemy = int(input("How many times do you want them to fight ? "))
    fight = 1
    guns = ["AK47" , "Magnum" , "other"]
    while fight <= enemy:
        number = random.randint(0,players-1)
        guns_number = random.randint(0,len(guns)-1)
        arr[number].attack(guns[guns_number])
        fight += 1
start(7)
```

Comment: You mean `self.life_left`

Comment: Additionally to what @match said, add `self` parameter to `life_left` definition - `def life_left(self, life)`

Comment: ... you should also use `self.life` inside `life_left` (and it have no argument)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `self` in the method definition and in calling the methods inside the class. here is the fixed code:

```
import random
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.life = 20

    def attack(self,gun):
        if (self.life <= 0):
            print("Dead")
        else:
            if gun is "AK47":
                self.life = self.life - 5
                self.life_left(self.life)
            elif gun is "Magnum":
                self.life = self.life - 4
                self.life_left(self.life)
            else:
                self.life = self.life - 1
                self.life_left(self.life)

    def life_left(self,life):
         print ("Life  :  " , str(life))


def start(players):
    a = 1
    arr = []
    while a <= players:
        arr.append("player" + str(a))
        arr[a-1] = Enemy()
        #print (arr[a-1])
        a += 1
    enemy = int(input("How many times do you want them to fight ? "))
    fight = 1
    guns = ["AK47" , "Magnum" , "other"]
    while fight <= enemy:
        number = random.randint(0,players-1)
        guns_number = random.randint(0,len(guns)-1)
        arr[number].attack(guns[guns_number])
        fight += 1
start(7)
```

Comment: Do we have to do such kind of thing everytime when we call a method of the same class or can we have an alternate method to this solution.

Comment: `self` is similar to `this` in other oop languages. take a look at [this](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)